# Generate an sql query from multiple tables, then create new table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a tricky bit of sql query I need to write.  To best explain it, I will post some pictures to show three tables.  The first two are tables which already contain data, the last table will be the table I need created using data from the first two:

[image: First table contains data]

[image: Second table contains data]

[image: Last table created from first and second table data]

Comment: do you want to build sql server query? or msaccess?

Comment: I am currently working in ms access but the schema will eventually be migrated to sql server.  During development however, I am using Access

Comment: EAV is not best for Relational DB.

Comment: The reason I need to use this approach is that I am working with an existing application which has thousands of rules defined to read table data in a particular format.  This format is my third table.  I would like to minimize the amount of code re-write after we change over to our new schema.  We are trying to normalize the data, which it currently isn't, but keep the application code re-write to a minimal.

Comment: Will A SQL server query do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN for each column you want to get in final table:

```
SELECT 
    Width.itemNumber,
    Width.itemValue as 'Width',
    Height.itemValue as 'Height',
    [Type].valueID as 'Type',
    Frame.valueID as 'Frame',
    Position.valueID as 'Position'
INTO third_table_name
FROM itemMaster_itemValue Width
JOIN itemMaster_itemValue Height ON Width.itemNumber=Height.itemNumber AND Height.itemPropertyID='Height'
JOIN itemMaster_EnumValue 'Type' ON Width.itemNumber=[Type].itemNumber AND [Type].itemPropertyID='Type'
JOIN itemMaster_EnumValue Frame ON Width.itemNumber=Frame.itemNumber AND Frame.itemPropertyID='Frame'
JOIN itemMaster_EnumValue Position ON Width.itemNumber=Position.itemNumber AND Position.itemPropertyID='Position'
WHERE Width.itemPropertyID='Width'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you actually are wanting to create a table for the third view or just a query (in access) / view (in MS SQL Server).  Here is how I would do it:

In MS-Access:

Step 1 (Which can end here if all you need is a way to see the data in this format)

```
TRANSFORM Max(P.vid) AS MaxOfvid
SELECT P.inum
FROM (SELECT itemNumber as inum, itemPropertyID as ival, itemValue as vid
FROM itemMaster_itemValue  
UNION
SELECT Enum.itemNumber AS inum, Enum.itemPropertyID AS ival, Enum.valueID AS vid
FROM itemMaster_EnumValue AS Enum)  AS P
GROUP BY P.inum
PIVOT P.ival;
```

Step 2 (If you need to actually create an additional table)

```
Select * INTO tableName FROM previousPivotQueryName;
```

That will get you what you need in Access.

The SQL Server part is a little different and can all be done in one T-SQL Statement dbo.test is the name of the table you will create... If you are creating a table for performance reasons then this statement can be put into a job and run nightly to create the table. The Drop Table line will have to be removed before the first time you run it or it will fail because the table will not exist yet:

```
Drop Table dbo.Test
Select * INTO dbo.Test FROM (
/*just use the following part if you only need a view*/ 
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT itemNumber as inum, itemPropertyID as ival, itemValue as vid
FROM dbo.itemMaster_itemValue  
UNION
SELECT Enum.itemNumber AS inum, Enum.itemPropertyID AS ival, Enum.valueID AS vid
FROM dbo.itemMaster_EnumValue AS Enum)  P
PIVOT (max(vid) FOR ival IN([Width],[Height],[Type],[Frame],[Position])) PV)PVT;
```

And that should get you what you need in the most efficient way possible without using a bunch of joins. :)